# file processing in C++

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if anybody can help me solving the following problem in C++:

I have a file where some time there is missing data i.e there are two consecutive TABs, then I need to transform the second TAB into "-999999" or "0" for example.
here is how the file looks like

```
     i_1   i_2   i_3   i_4   i_5
j_1  12          14          16
j_2        11    17    25  
j_3  44                51    65
```

I want to compute the mean of the elements on the first row i.e( 12,14 and 16) as:

```
sum+=tab[i][j];
mean = sum/5; (considering empty spaces =0)
```

thank you

Comment: Are i_1, i_2, j_1 etc.. part of the file?

Comment: Spaces or tabs between values? Values are always have 2 digits?

Comment: If the number of columns is fixed, then you don't need to convert anything... Just sum up what's there.

Comment: Yes, i_1, i_2,,,j_1,j_2,,, are part of the file
the separators are TABs and the values are of different number of digits.
the number of columns will be changed each time we have a new file

Comment: And do you actually have to build a 2D array or just calculate the averages of the rows? The latter will be much easier.

Comment: I've built a 2D array and everything is okey, but the missing data do mix everything !!

Comment: Obviously not everything is ok if you've got problems. Show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

bool const compress_tokens = false;
bool const table_width = ...;

std::ifstream inp("filename");

// parsed grid
std::list<std::vector<std::string> > table;

std::string strbuf;
std::vector<std::string> vecbuf;
while(inp.getline(strbuf))
{
    vecbuf.clear();
    boost::split(vecbuf, strbuf, boost::is_any_of("\t"), compress_tokens);
    assert(vecbuf.size() == table_width);
    table.push_back(vecbuf);
}
```

Comment: open file, read line by line, split each line and put tokens into a vector, append a vector to a list of vectors representing a 2D table